# Using %substr with NASM assembler

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I copy-pasted the following code from the NASM documentation pdf page 46:

```
%substr mychar ’xyzw’ 1 ; equivalent to %define mychar ’x’
```

And after assembling it I get the following error:

```
`%substr` requires string as second parameter
```

But atfer I change ’xyzw’ to 'xyzw' or "xyzw" it wroks fine. So what I Am missing here?

Comment: Most probably they messed up the PDF - possibly some word processor tried to be a bit too smart about quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is shown in the [online documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.2.3)

```
%substr mychar 'xyzw' 1       ; equivalent to %define mychar 'x'
```

In general, for preprocessor string functions it talks about strings and string literals, which are explained [here](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.4) and can be enclosed by single quotes, double quotes and backticks:

> String constants are character strings used in the context of some pseudo-instructions, namely the DB family and INCBIN (where it represents a filename.) They are also used in certain preprocessor directives.
>
> A string constant looks like a character constant, only longer.

And about [character constants](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.2) (where the delimiters are actually explained):

> A character string consists of up to eight characters enclosed in either single quotes (`'...'`), double quotes (`"..."`) or backquotes (`` `...` ``). Single or double quotes are equivalent to NASM (except of course that surrounding the constant with single quotes allows double quotes to appear within it and vice versa); the contents of those are represented verbatim. Strings enclosed in backquotes support C-style -escapes for special characters.

As said in the comment, most probably the PDF was messed up by a word processor too eager to typeset nice characters instead of the right ones.

Comment: Thank's, but way it doesn't work with the back-quotes? are there any known cases (instructions) where a string is accepted with one kind of quotes and not others?

Comment: It works with back-quotes I believe. Your code not working is using some kind of pretty-quotes, not from them `', ", \`` group. Yours `’`.

Comment: @MaykelJakson It does work with backquotes `\`` but not with the character that you cut and pasted `’`.

Comment: @Matteo Italia, the quote you wrote is about **Character String**, something like \U12345678, which is the one limited to 8 characters, but the problem here is with **String Constant**, which can contain any number of characters.

Comment: @MaykelJakson Specifically the character you cut and pasted is, in Unicode, a RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm

Comment: @MaykelJakson: sorry, I mixed up the quotes (pun intended); I'll fix it now.

Comment: @RossRidge the problem is with the pdf reader, it treats the symbol ' in italic, as Right Single Quotation Mark.

Comment: @MaykelJakson Looking deeper at the problem, it appears to be a mistake in the Perl script used to generate the PostScript file that's used to generate the PDF. The mistake is that they're using a value of 39 for the single quote character `'` and while this is correct encoding for that character in ASCII and Unicode, it's not the correct encoding for the standard PDF fonts the manual is using. Instead the value 39 encodes the "quoteright" character in PDF fonts.